# Why is the Monte Carlo integration dimensionally independent?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, monte-carlo

Suppose that the random variables $x_1, x_2, ... x_N$ are drawn independently from the probability density function $p(x)$.

[image]

Now the convergence rate of a *deterministic numerical* integration method is $O(N^{-2/d})$.

Why does the Monte Carlo integration method yield a convergence rate of $O(N^{-1/2})$ ?

Comment: The standard deviation of this average is$O(N^{-1/2})$.

Comment: This statement does not help me.

Comment: There is a basic idea in sampling that the standard deviation of an average is $O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}})$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation may help.

Comment: And why doesn't this deviation apply to a deterministic numerical integration?

Comment: For Monte Carlo the sample size is the key factor.  The dimension will effect the standard deviation of of one sample, but it does not effect the deviation of the average ,except as a constant multiplier.  When doing a deterministic integration, the grid refinement depends on the dimension.